# VMware workstation with GNS3 remote access

Tags: internet, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to set up a home lab that I can access remotely when I am away with work through the Internet.

I have VMware workstation 12 player setup with multiple VMs installed. I am also using GNS3 with ASA and 3745 images loaded in.

My host OS is windows 10. So far I have been unsuccessful in setting up the network and attaching the VMs so that I can access it remotely.

Comment: What did you already try? How did you connected the VM to your local network (bridge? host-only, vmwares local NAT?). Did you set up port forwarding? Or what is your local LAN setup at all? Etc etc.